# How to get a Queue object from a TensorFlow graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In TensorFlow I have a graph that has in it a string_input_producer that is used in it's input pipeline.

I am loading the graph from a checkpoint file, so I do not have access to the original object when it was created. Nonetheless, I need to run the enqueue method of this object.

I have tried getting the FIFOQueue object using get_operation_by_name and get_tensor_by_name, which obviously did not work because the queue is neither an operation nor a tensor. Is there any function like the mentioned that would do what I want? (fake e.g. get_queue_by_name) How can I solve my problem otherwise?

Comment: I do not have a lot of experience in TensorFlow, so the answer may be something easy that I just did not notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that as of today that is not possible. However, you can call methods of the queue object by getting them using `get_operation_by_name`. For example `get_operation_by_name("queue_name/enqueue")`. You can also make your own Queue object which internally simply calls the corresponding graph operations.